# Maven fails to retrieve its plugins

Tags: maven, archiva

When i try to deploy a file using maven, i keep getting errors, and i am at my wits' end on how to fix them.

When i use default Archiva internal repository, which is configured as a proxy to maven's central repository, git the following:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5 in http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.internal has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4 in http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.internal has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7 in http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.internal has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3 in http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.internal has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3 in http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.internal has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5 in http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.internal has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8 in http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.internal has elapsed or updates are forced
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2 in http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of archiva.internal has elapsed or updates are forced
Downloading: http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.396s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 16 11:22:27 MSK 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/ivantruskov/.m2/repository), archiva.internal (http://127.0.0.1:8090/archiva/repository/internal/)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

When i turn mirror off in settings, what i get instead is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.816s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 16 11:36:38 MSK 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/ivantruskov/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
[ivantruskov@server-visionlabs-ru ~]$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=sql.zip -DrepositoryId=externals -Durl=http://192.168.1.109:8090/repository/externals/
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.586s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 16 11:45:50 MSK 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/ivantruskov/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Which is not better at all.

What could be the reason?

Update: there is my [settings.xml](http://pastebin.com/HKp8XJTM).

I am working from the local network, that connects to the internet through router.

Comment: It looks like you didn't manage to turn off the mirror in your settings. Could you post your `settings.xml`? Also, try doing `mvn -U clean install` to force rechecking of your remote repository.

Comment: Error with second log, sorry. Pasted actual one now

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Your `settings.xml` would still help :)

Comment: I am in local network. Does router cont as proxy?

Added paste of settings.xml

Comment: @Srv19 do you have to set proxy settings (e.g. in the browser or other applications), when you want to connect to the internet?

Comment: @Rubinium no, never had to; also, repo.maven.apache.org pings fine.

Comment: @Srv19 that you can ping repo.maven.apache... does not mind. Your maven tries to connect to it but fails. You had written: "When i use default Archiva internal repository, which is configured as a proxy to maven's central repository, git the following:" so you use a proxy hmm? If true than change your <proxy> settings in your settings.xml

Comment: To that i can only refer to http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/userguide/using-repository.html

Answer (score 0):

While I note above you said you can ping it, the error in the second set is most likely an `UnknownHostException`, meaning it can't resolve that domain. You can use `-e` to confirm that, and `-X` to get a lot more debugging information during resolution. As a commenter also mentioned, you should use `-U` to stop Maven from caching the failed resolution until the issue is resolved.

As for the first set of failures, this is probably due to a similar problem inside Archiva. You can look at `logs/archiva.log` under the installation to confirm if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

using the -U switch worked for me:
    `mvn clean package -U`.

@Zoltán has already answered that above.